# Do you know a website which can search a place from map and create a URL to share

Tags: google-maps

I remembered a website made by a Japanese which can search a place from a map and create a URL to share to friends. Could you tell me which website can do that?

Comment: all of the well known mapping locations have an ability to make a coordinate based "link" you can send to a friend. bing yahoo google and Acme which uses google and some Usgs mappings http://mapper.acme.com/?ll=36.54854,139.17189&z=14&t=N at Acme it is very simple, just select the LINK button, and the resulting web address in the browser will be coordinate based and set zoom and all. Which one is made by japanese I dont know.

Comment: @Psycogeek: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Google Maps](http://maps.google.com) has a way of sharing maps, just click the link (looks like a chain) on the top right when you have on screen what you want to share...

[Here is a link to where i work :)](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=wyevale+nurseries&hl=en&ll=52.073387,-2.774906&spn=0.019625,0.052872&sll=51.933259,-3.304825&sspn=0.162575,0.422974&vpsrc=6&hq=wyevale+nurseries&radius=15000&t=m&z=15&iwloc=A)